# Don't know how to build task：jekyll、octopress

Tags: ruby, rake, jekyll

i want build a blog using jekyll and octopress.
but an error happened when i run `bundle exec rake git@github.com:congmo/congmo.github.com.git --trace`

```
rake aborted! 
Don't know how to build task 'git@github.com:congmo/congmo.github.com.git'      
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[ ]'  
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:111:in `invoke_task' c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `bl ock (2 levels) in top_level' 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `ea ch'   
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `bl ock in top_level' 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `s tandard_exception_handling' 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `to p_level' 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `bl ock in run' 
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `s tandard_exception_handling' c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `ru n' c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'

c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

somebody meet the same problem?could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the error message, you didn't specify a correct `rake` task. If you are using Octopress chances are that you wanted do something like `rake generate`, `rake deploy`, or `rake gen_deploy`, but that's hard to know without more info. Make sure you read and understand Octopress' documentation before you start blogging with it.

Comment: thank you!I think so maybe the tast is not corrent,but my github id is congmo.I use these commond just as the Octopress document.i really don't know why.and then i run    rake gen_deply.    Successfully generated site: source -> public
## Deploying website via Rsync
FAILED

Comment: You don't deploy to Github pages using rsync, but with git. You really should read the documentation again: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

Comment: right,I really used this documentation.but something wrong when run rake git@github.com:congmo/congmo.github.com.and now i aslo don't know why.

Comment: You are still calling a task that doesn't exist. `git@github.com:congmo/congmo.github.com` os not a task. This is what you have to do: 1. `rake setup_github_pages` (only once for configuration). 2. `rake generate`. 3. `rake deploy`.